# Change the icon of an applescript-called notification

Tags: applescript, macos, notifications

With OSX Mavericks we now can make [notifications with applescript](http://www.macosautomation.com/mavericks/notifications/index.html) pretty easily. However, there doesn’t seem to be a way to change the icon that appears to a custom one. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/aslr_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW224) `display notification` does not have a parameter to change te icon.

`Display notification` will use the icon of your script. One of your option is to change the icon of your bundle (cf screen). [image]

Comment: That is actually not working. You can't set an icon for your script bundle this way. At least this is not working on macOS 10.14.6

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice way to do it. You must Show the content of your app and change the AutomatorApplet.icns inside "Your App.app/Contents/Resources/AutomatorApplet.icns"

Comment: That’s the same thing as the accepted answer. The `Resources` shown is a representation of the app bundle.